# Phonegap - iOS Keyboard and Dropdown 'compress' webview because of vh unit

Tags: android, html, ios, css, cordova

With an ionic/phonegap application I've this issue (Only on iOS).

When the user need to write something o select and option the iOS control (keyboard or dropdown) appears and when it does the web-view is compress to half. I'm using vh and vw measure unit in CSS.

What I've done/tried:

[This post in ionic's forum](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/keyboard-shrinks-view-ios/21026/5) The OP solved it by changing vh and vw units back to pixels. That's no a solution for me.

[Ionic keyboard plugin](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ios-keyboard-push-content-out-of-view/6715) using the method `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);` didn't work. Tried with false and true.

[Add parameters to the meta tag](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/keyboard-shrinks-view-ios/21026) Non working. My current meta:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />`

Image when keyboard is hidden:

[image: When keyboard is hidden]

Image when keyboard is shown:

[image: When keyboard is shown]

On the 2nd image you can barely read **left text - right text** because the height for the input is 24vh.

I create a dummy page where I **do not use** vh and vw and this works ok. On Android works fine too. It seems that when de keyboard or dropdown comes up the height of viewport is resize and vh size adapts to it.

Since I can't change it to **px** I'm looking for other alternatives

Comment: vh is buggy on ios, see http://caniuse.com/#search=vh for more info and a polyfill

Comment: @jcesarmobile tried that but no luck. Content is being compress. I need to use vh to make a responsive layout. Can't change it back to px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent container(s) that holds the input element cannot contain height:100% or 100vh on iOS if thats what you are trying to do. I had this similar issue on iOS timepicker reducing the screen size and showing blank just like yours.

This usually happens if the keyboard height is half compared to the screen height of iOS device. On larger screens like iPhone 6, this issue doesn't happen.

I used `min-height:480px` and `height:100vh` on the same container that gets resized. It fixed my issue on the smaller devices.

This `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);` is not required.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I did the app to work in android. Now it should be work on iOS. As it has ionic this shouldn't be a problem. on Android the keyboard overlaps over the content (it's ok) and the select option is presented in a scrollable list. On iOS both keyboard and the select an option control shrink the view because of the vh unit. The 480px you said it based on the iphone model? Or it will works on the others? Thanks for your answer, btw. I'll try asap.

Comment: 480px was based on the smallest screen device. There isn't an iOS device less than 480. I think the reason the keyboard happens is because when you use vh, the height of the container is set to less than 480px when you open the keyboard. This was the only workaround i could get to work on iOS. Android doesn't affect the webview when keyboard opens. Did you try it?

Comment: I almost got it. I need to use `min-height` but with % instead of px. Also, the `disableScroll` is needed so the content won't go off screen. I think I can make it from here. Thanks!